# Dynamical Image loaded from php after javascript need to run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, image

I have page with image loading Dynamical from php.The image height is 
various px size(70,130,100,60).my need is how can get the image size currently viewed in page automatically in alertbox i try same code is not working.please help

code

```
<?php
foreach ($images as $image) { 
    ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="img_test" id="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" width="70" style="max-height:70px" onclick="imagesize(this)" />
<?php
}?>

<script>
       $( window ).load(function() {

        $( ".img_test" ).each(function( index ) {
            alert('Height: '+$(this).height());
        });
       });
       function imagesize(obj){
           alert($(obj).height());
       }
</script>
```

if we click the image the height will display.in page load after automatically can't be display

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My concept is align the image from his height.the width is standard is 70,the height of the image is not,when align the image get the height after completely image load in that css class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that it's navigator (client) which load image and PHP is running into your server and send text to client.

Use a listener `.on` to get event 'click'.

Moreover, use `$(document).ready` and not .load to wait that images are loading

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="img_test" id="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" width="70" style="max-height:70px" />
<?php } ?>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".img_test" ).each(function(){
        alert('Height: '+$(this).height());
    });

    $(".img_test").on("click", function(){
           alert($(this).height());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3c9CN/

Comment: i would use `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` as your images may not have fully loaded and will give you a false height.  `$(document).ready` only waits until all the html is parsed where as `$(window).load` will wait until all the objects are loaded

Comment: but that also i have checked there is no result,the image take automatically height that height need to alert.